# Как при каждой итерации создавать новый массив с новыми элементами?

Tags: javascript

То есть мне нужно чтобы при первой итерации в цикле создался массив, допустим с элементами [1,2,3] и он бы улетел в общий массив с данными, а при следующей итерации создался уже новый массив с новыми элементами [5,7,8] и так, пока цикл не закончится. Как такое сделать?

Comment: По какому принципу будут создаваться элементы в массиве? Или  Вам просто нужно, чтобы с новой итерацией они не совпадали с предыдущими?

Comment: @Alexandr_Yakovlev test.push(elem), где elem = ['name', 'surname', 'age']. А общий массив, получается, должен содержать [ ['name', 'surname', 'age'], и т.д. ]

Answer (score 0):

```
let main = [];

for(let i = 1; i <= 2; i++){
    let tempArr = [];
    let till = i+3;
    for(let j = 1; j <= till; j++){
        tempArr.push(j.toString())
    }
    main.push(tempArr)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для генерации случайных данных о пользователях можно воспользоваться [faker](https://github.com/faker-js/faker), тогда:

```
import faker from '@faker-js/faker'

const getRandomUsers = (count, minAge, maxAge) => {
  const getRandomAge = (min, max) =>  Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min )
  return Array(count).fill(true).map( _ => {
    return [
      faker.name.firstName(),
      faker.name.lastName(),
      getRandomAge(minAge, maxAge)
    ]
  })
}

const users = getRandomUsers(10, 18, 60)

console.log(users)
```